# Perl: get array in terminal until user type ctrl+z or ctrl+c

Tags: perl

I need to make a program that receive a array of strings and the list should end with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> (unix) or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>(win). I have been reading how to do it but i dont understand. I dont want the answer I just one a simple explanation of how to capture the stop without finish my program

```
for $i (0...8){
   print "Give me a name of a city: \n";
   $sentence[$i] = <STDIN>; #get value
}
```

My answer was:

```
print "Give me a name of a city: \n";
$a=0;
$SIG{'INT'} = sub {$a=1;}; #change de flag
while ($a == 0){
   $string = <STDIN>;
   push @sentence, $string;
   if($a == 0){
      print "Give me a name of a city: $a\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: You're worrying too much about the Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z. Those characters don't appear in the data your program receives. What is wrong with the code you have shown? It looks fine to me except that your `for` loop won't stop until you have entered nine cities. What is it that you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the [`eof`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html) (end of file) operator, but I'm hesitant to recommend it as it looks like you're following a tutorial

Here's how your code would look. The last line prints each element of the `@sentence` array back to the console so that you can see the program is still running. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> signals the end of the input and makes `eof` return a *true* value

```
for $i ( 0 ... 8 ) {
    print "Give me a name of a city: \n";
    $sentence[$i] = <STDIN>;    #get value
    last if eof;
}

print for @sentence;
```

Please remember that this isn't a method you'll see often in programming

Answer (score 0):

You can catch and handle signals in Perl, see for example [this blog post](http://perltricks.com/article/37/2013/8/18/Catch-and-Handle-Signals-in-Perl/). Here is a scripts that checks for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on Unix:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my @sentence;

local $SIG{INT} = sub { die };

for my $i (0...8) {
   print "Give me a name of a city: \n";
   eval {
       $sentence[$i] = <STDIN>; #get value
   };
   last if $@;
}

say "";
print for @sentence;
```